# How can I differentiate a Manufacturing order from a back order ? Odoo V15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I need to know, how I can differentiate a Manufacturing order (MO) from a backorder.

A backorder is created, when only a part of the MO is beeing processed. MO and backorder are in the same model, so a automated action, which should only be triggered on the MO is also beeingt triggered on the backorder, because the automated action refers to the model of both.

How can I differentiate them ? I just want the automated action to be triggered on the MO. Not the backorder.